# Synchronize .bundle_pool with local update site?

Tags: eclipse, pde

I have a local eclipse P2 update site containing some features based on some plugins that I have created.

I have added this update site to my target platform and can add plugins from the local update site to my PDE projects. When I look at the paths to the plugins it points to:

C:\Users\mm\workspace_helios.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core.bundle_pool\plugins

I have now updated the plugins and rebuild my update site. But instead of using the updated plugins the plugins stored in the above location are still used.

How do I force a rebuild of my update site to also update the plugins located in the bundle_pool ?

Comment: You never accept any answers or give any feedback. Why should people bother answering your questions?

Comment: Ah so thats what the arrows/cross are for, I'll get right onto it :-)

Answer (score 1):

What worked better for me (see also https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=323289#c7) is renaming the .target definition file, then re-starting Eclipse with the "-clean" option, then setting the renamed target definition as the new target platform. At least when previously removing the .bundle_pool directory entirely this has reproducably re-loaded all bundles properly.

Answer (score 0):

Open the target platform editor, and temporarily disable then reenable a plugin. The changes will cause Eclipse to re-read the target platform (I think).

Comment: Have tried that, but it still uses the old versions from the folder:

workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\.bundle_pool\plugins

it seems that those plugins/.jar are only updated when I increment the version number and then rebuild.